# Why can't I specialize class template with a templated class?

Tags: c++, class, templates

Why is the below partial specialization not allowed? The class is specialized with a templated class:

```
template <class T>
class ClassT{};

template<class F>
class ClassF{};

//error here
template<>
template <class T>
class ClassF <ClassT<T> >{};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ClassF<ClassT<int> > ftx; //no error
}
```

The error:

```
tester.cpp(8): error C2910: 'ClassF<ClassT<T>>' : cannot be explicitly specialized
```

Comment: Get rid of the first `template<>`.

Comment: Thank you, that solves the problem in this minimum working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original problem I was having is that I forgot to include the header of the class I was trying to specialize! Of course that would never work but the error message was not clear enough: I did not get `undefined identifier` or something similar which would have been more useful. So that's why I was fiddling with syntax, trying `template<>` trick etc.